# Turn C code intended to be compiled into R function

Tags: c, r, word2vec

I'm trying to learn how to leverage C code in R functions, specifically because I want to be able to use [word2vec](https://code.google.com/p/word2vec/) in R.  word2vec is available as C code and, on a linux box, I can use `make` to compile it and then `./word2vec -options` to build the model and do fun things with it.  I would like to take the C code, as is, and essentially wrap it into an R function so I could call, `word2vec(words)` and have it return the calculated matrix.

So, is there a way to include C code which is written to be compiled into an executable or alternatively, just call the compiled executable?